# Abrir link dentro de uma div

Tags: html, wordpress

Uso um plugin para gerenciar minhas postagens no *Wordpress*, porém eu gostaria de fazer ele abrir dentro de uma `DIV` específica.

Que no qual é a `#main-view`.

Hoje ele se encontra assim : `target="_parent"`

Abaixo segue o código do plugin.

```html
<div class="gw-gopf-post">
 <div class="gw-gopf-post-header">
  <div class="gw-gopf-post-overlay">{{post_overlay_buttons}}</div>
  {{post_media}}
 </div>
 <div class="gw-gopf-post-content-wrap">
  <div class="gw-gopf-post-content">
   <div class="gw-gopf-post-title"><h2><a href="{{post_link}}" target="_parent">{{post_title}}</a></h2></div>
   
  </div>       
 </div>            
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veja se este código com `XMLHttpRequest()` funciona no seu Wordpress:

Substitua todo o `<a></a>` por este:

```
<a href='javascript: document.getElementById("main-view").innerHTML="Carregando...";xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){if(xhr.readyState==4&&xhr.status==200){document.getElementById("main-view").innerHTML=xhr.responseText;}};xhr.open("GET","{{post_link}}",true);xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","text/html");xhr.send();' target="_parent">{{post_title}}</a>
```

Este código irá puxar todo o HTML da URL desejada para dentro da div `#main-view` (necessário que a URL seja do mesmo domínio).

Comment: ele funciona mesmo se a div for de um subdominio  ?  por exemplo ... essa página do wordpress é um iframe dentro de um site principal e quando os usuários clicarem nos links delas possam abrir na div da página do dominio principal ?

Comment: Cara, só testando, mas acredito que sim.

Comment: não funcionou ...desativou o link do texto.